# HTML - about table cell width

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my webpage I have the following:

```
<table style="width:1000px">
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td style="width:500px"></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Can I assume that the first and last cell width will be both 250px? or should the behavior be browser dependent here?

Edit:

I am assuming that the first and last cells are empty

Comment: I think they are dynamic due to the content.

Comment: If you want to force them to be 250px each, you need to specify that in the css, otherwise it will depend on the width of the content, as @DanielCheung stated.

Comment: Does the table style width have an influence?

Comment: They are empty cells

Comment: You need to specify explicity. Empty cells cant occupy space like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ammcom what everyone has said so far is correct. If you go that route and set your empty cells with an explicit width, make sure you also set this in your CSS:
`table { table-layout: fixed; }` This will make the table honor your explicit widths like if you use 50% for two empty columns. The default behavior is: `table-layout: auto` which makes the table prioritize it's width according to content within the cells.